# link tag redirect issue in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have links saved in the firebase DB, when I click "save" the link it will updated but when I click to the link icon it redirect me to home page.
Example:
The link in the DB is "www.instagram.com", when I click the icon it will redirect me to the home with this url "localhost:3000/www.instagram.com", but when I do the console log it logs only "www.instagram.com", can somebody help me please?

formInputs it's a simple object

```
<a
    target="_blank"
    href={formInputs.ig}
    onClick={() => {
        console.log(formInputs.ig);
    }}
>
    <FontAwesomeIcon
        className="icons"
        icon={faInstagram}
        color="purple"
        size="2x"
    />
</a>
```

I tryed to use the Link component from react-router-dom but it do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: please try to use a full **absolute** URL together with the protocol. Instead of a short one. In this case, can change the value to `https://www.instagram.com`.

Document source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Possible values of `href`:

- An absolute URL - points to another website (like href="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
- A relative URL - points to a file within a website (like href="default.htm")

The key difference is the `//` at the beginning. Without it, your browser is considering your given `"www.instagram.com"` as a relative URL and is trying to calculate the path based on your current location.

And if you're only using `//www.instagram.com`, the browser will use the same protocol as the current page, e.g. `http://localhost` -> `http://www.instagram.com`

Comment: it work! thank you so much and sorry for this basic mistake